# Android: Adding a divider into a list item with dynamic height

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently trying to create a list item similar to the one in [the official design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/lists.html). Still missing is the vertical divider next to the button/image on the right side of each item. Most people seem to use a separate View with a fixed width for that, but the height doesn't scale in my case. It's only shown when I set a fixed height for the divider itself or the parent RelativeLayout. Is it possible to let it scale automatically?

My layout XML for the list item looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sensors_list_img"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sensors_list_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sensors_list_img"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_angle_right" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_divider"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sensors_list_details"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You say that the image view scale. looks like it isn't. it's match parent height and not wrap content. maybe the content inside scales.

Comment: You're correct. I did that so that they can center their content, but that wasn't necessary. I changed width and height of the images to wrap_content. The main problem remains, though: That single View doesn't extend it's height to match that of its parent.

Comment: Please, check the new update and tell me the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign an height related to the image like:

```
android:alignTop="@id/myimage"
android:alignBottom="@id/myimage"
```

otherwise you can create a xml drawable and use it with an `ImageView` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

**Update**
Remember `android:shape="line"` doesn't work without `stroke`

Comment: Using alignTop and alignBottom didn't change much, especially since layout_height is still required. I tried it with both wrap_content and match_parent, but the line wasn't visible in either case. I'll give the drawable ImageView a shot. Anyway, what would be the reason for the View not to match its height with that of the parent? There are quite a lot of workarounds, but I'm especially interested in the reasoning behind all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go with a `LinearLayout` as a parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensors_list_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sensors_list_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_divider"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sensors_list_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_angle_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, for the sake of brevity in my example I removed an image which both TextViews are referencing. I just edited it back in. Besides that, your example doesn't show the thin red line. That's exactly my problem: The single "View" doesn't extend it's height to that of it's parent.

Answer (score -1):

```
Check this 
listView.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Comment: That's not he want. he want a divider inside the item. divides the image and other items.

Comment: The question is about the vertical divider within a list item, not between list items.